# docker - change default login user

Tags: linux, unix, docker

When I run

```
docker run -t -i centos /bin/bash
```

It always logins as root by default. Let's say I already have user "myuser", how do I configure to login as "myuser" by default?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To run as myuser you could simply use `USER myuser` in your Dockerfile, as written in the official [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user).

Comment: Oh snap! You're right. My fault in not looking at the documentation at first.

Comment: I might be misreading the docs, but Dockerfile seems to be used for assembling an image, not for running an existing one.